# ifconfig shows different interface after unplugging and replugging usb cable (ethernet over usb)

Tags: usb, ethernet, ifconfig

I am connecting my ARM64 development board with an USB port that is configured as peripheral and with the necessary drivers for the usb ethernet gadget to my Ubuntu 20.04.1 host PC. I am connecting my board to my host PC with a usb male to male cable. After that ifconfig -a shows me a usb0 interface:

```
usb0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether ae:1f:07:23:57:06  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

when I unplug the cable and replug it, ifconfig -a the interface has a new name:

```
enx7ef758273481: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 7e:f7:58:27:34:81  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

When I set up the interface (ifconfig  ) the connection to the board seems to be much faster when the interface name is usb0. On the board the interface name is also usb0 and unplugging and replugging changes nothing on the board.
dmesg shows me the following output:

```
[   89.145321] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   89.295266] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=a4a2, bcdDevice= 5.15
[   89.295269] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   89.295270] usb 1-5: Product: RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget
[   89.295271] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.32+gfa6c3168595c with dwc3-gadget
[   89.310530] cdc_subset: probe of 1-5:1.0 failed with error -22
[   89.311814] cdc_subset 1-5:1.1 usb0: register 'cdc_subset' at usb-0000:00:14.0-5, Linux Device, ae:1f:07:23:57:06
[   89.311829] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_subset
[   89.311846] cdc_ether: probe of 1-5:1.0 failed with error -16
[   89.311868] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[  213.382913] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  213.382990] cdc_subset 1-5:1.1 usb0: unregister 'cdc_subset' usb-0000:00:14.0-5, Linux Device
[  215.220424] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  215.370333] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=a4a2, bcdDevice= 5.15
[  215.370337] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  215.370338] usb 1-5: Product: RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget
[  215.370338] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.32+gfa6c3168595c with dwc3-gadget
[  215.371653] cdc_subset: probe of 1-5:1.0 failed with error -22
[  215.372954] cdc_ether 1-5:1.0 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-5, CDC Ethernet Device, 7e:f7:58:27:34:81
[  215.379101] cdc_ether 1-5:1.0 enx7ef758273481: renamed from usb0
```

Why is the interface renamed and how can I avoid that behaviour?

**EDIT**
I figured out the removing the cdc_ether driver (sudo rmmod cdc_ether) before replugging the cable back in solves the issue. But I think that's not I beautiful workaround and I would like to understand why it is renamed and why that affects the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try remove your device and create this file

```
/etc/systemd/network/10-usb0.link
```

with following content

```
[Match]
Driver=cdc_ether 

[Link]
Name=usb0
```

Let udev read the rules anew with

```
sudo udevadm control -R
```

[source](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html)

Comment: Thanks! I edited the udevadm command as there was a typo