# Is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS has RTL8188EU Monitor Integrated?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek, tp-link

- 1.I am using dekstop-OS Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with TP-LINK WN722N V3 Adapter Plugged in. When installation give me 2 choices install with
  "Ubuntu Driver for third party services"(RTL8188EU) or without
  adapter driver. I use "Install Ubuntu Driver For Third Party
  Services". i checked iwconfig but its show as `wlxc006c372481a  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"kamar_atas"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>" Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz`, it
  should be wlan0?. **How to Rename**

---

2. Does Ubuntu Integrated driver(RTL8188EU)have monitor mode?
   `configuration: broadcast=yes driver=8188eu driverversion=5.19.0-32-generic`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename a network interface in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317036/how-to-rename-a-network-interface-in-20-04)

Comment: Why should it be `wlan0`?

Comment: Please adapt this to your driver and wanted name. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428245/ifconfig-shows-different-interface-after-unplugging-and-replugging-usb-cable-et#1434425

Comment: so i can simplified airmon-ng

Comment: To find your device capabilities: `iw list` You may find something like: Supported interface modes:
   * IBSS
   * managed
   * AP
   * AP/VLAN
   * monitor
   * P2P-client
   * P2P-GO
   * P2P-device

Comment: work tho. but the network interface is gone. cant connect any wifi